# replace multiple words that look the same in a string

Tags: php, string, replace, str-replace, keyword

I have a little problem in PHP.

```
$string = "[:string] has [:int] [:string] and [:int] [:string]";
```

I just wanna modify (probably with str_replace) it with:

```
$string = "He has 5 apples and 3 bananas";
```

How could I do that?

(Classic str_replace() will modify all [:int] with the same word,

and is not what I want).

Thank you very much...

Comment: `preg_replace_callback`

Comment: You should use arrays

Comment: Use `sprintf`: `sprintf('%s has %u %s and %u %s', 'He', 5, 'apples', 3, 'bananas');`. Optionally first replace the placeholders using `str_replace`: `$format = str_replace(['[:string]', '[:int]'], ['%s', '%u'], $string)`.

Comment: I don't know where the keywords are in the string. And I don't wanna display the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following regex, to capture all groups to replace and then iterate over it.

```
\[:([^\]]+)\]
```

Or you can just use `preg_replace_callback` and pass an desired replace function to it.

```
$data = [...];
preg_replace_callback('/\[:([^\]]+)\]/', $str, function (&$matches) use ($data) {
    return doSomethingWithMatches..
});
```

Comment: I do not quite understand. Can you show, detailed, on my example please?

Comment: I understand now. Thank you very much. Usefull answer.